# How can I allow my phone and computer to see each other to enable use of KDE Connect while both are on a VPN?

Tags: networking, android, vpn, 19.04, kde-connect

I am on Ubuntu 19.04 and have loved using the excellent functionality of KDE Connect to link my Android phone (Galaxy S9) and computer. However I would also like the protection of a VPN while browsing the internet on both of these devices. Enabling a VPN on both devices does not allow PC/phone to see each other despite being on the same LAN. My question is how do I allow the connection between these two devices outside of the VPN? I am assuming I may need to forward ports or exclude the traffic between these devices from the VPN to make this happen but I cannot figure out how to to do this in Ubuntu 19.04. Any help is greatly appreciated!